# Build failure when using Objective-C & C++ framework in iOS Widget Extension

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, widget

I'm trying to add an Objective-C framework to a Widget Extension but it fails to build when I try to initialise an instance of the main public class.

I have a bridging header and the compiler recognises it - code completion works in the widget code - but I have a number of undefined symbols errors.

The framework works in the iOS app.

It is included in the Library Search Paths for the extension.

I believe the framework is using C++ because of a comment referring to a .mm file.

Using `lipo -info` on outputs `Architectures in the fat file: {path} are: x86_64 arm64`

Should it be possible to use it in a Widget Extension? Is there some objc/c/c++ library I need to add to get it to work?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      ByteArray::alloc(int) in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      ByteArray::alloc(int) in TheFramework.a(SomeOtherClass.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      -[TheFramework initWithName:] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      SomeClass::CreatePublicKey() in TheFramework.a(SomeOtherClass.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      -[TheFramework dealloc] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      -[TheFramework initWithName:] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      -[TheFramework getDataFromXml:] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      -[TheFramework getCommandFromXml:] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      -[TheFramework setConnectionDetails:] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      -[TheFramework connect:] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      -[TheFramework connect] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      ...
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      -[TheFramework dealloc] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      -[TheFramework initWithName:] in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      ByteArray::decRef() in TheFramework.a(SomeClass.o)
      SomeClass::Initialise() in TheFramework.a(SomeOtherClass.o)
      SomeClass::~SomeClass() in TheFramework.a(SomeOtherClass.o)
      SomeClass::CreatePublicKey() in TheFramework.a(SomeOtherClass.o)
      ByteArray::decRef() in TheFramework.a(SomeOtherClass.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You need to link with the C++ standard library, or use `clang++` instead of `clang`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go

Comment: @molbdnilo That worked thanks. If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. For anyone else with the same problem I just needed to add libc++.tbd in Link Binary with Libraries.